# How can I use a default value in a Select query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, select, default-value

I would like to use a default value for a column that should be used if no rows is returned. Is that possible in PostgreSQL? How can I do it? Or is there any other way I can solve this?

E.g. something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(post_id) AS max_id DEFAULT 0 FROM my_table WHERE org_id = 3
```

And if there is no rows with `org_id = 3` in the table I want to return `0`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
SELECT coalesce(MAX(post_id),0) AS max_id FROM my_table WHERE org_id = 3
```

or

```
SELECT case count(*) when 0 then 0 else MAX(post_id) end AS max_id
FROM my_table 
WHERE org_id = 3;
```

if you want max(post_id) to be `null` when there is 1 row but post_id is null

*<sub>[dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=63aad1acfcbdaf661b8264a3beea57df)</sub>*

Answer (score 20):

If you want to show `0` (alas 1 row) when your query returns 0 rows, then you could use:

```
SELECT COALESCE( 
        ( SELECT MAX(post_id) FROM my_table WHERE org_id = 3 )
               , 0) AS max_id
```

Comment: How can this be done for more than one column?

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT 
  coalesce(MAX(post_id),0) AS max_id 
FROM 
  my_table 
WHERE 
  org_id = 3
```

The above do not work if you want to use default name for name field and it works only if you use number field . The below query works for all type of fields..

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(
   (SELECT column_name FROM my_table WHERE id = -1), 
   'default_value'
  ) AS column_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

I cannot get either of the above to work.

Here is what I found to work for this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.max_id, B.dflt) FROM (
SELECT MAX(post_id) AS max_id FROM my_table WHERE org_id = 3) A
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 0 AS dflt) B
       ON 1 = 1
```

I realize not an elegant solution but does the job.

Comment: `SELECT coalesce(MAX(post_id),0) AS max_id FROM my_table WHERE org_id = 3` works fine for me.

Comment: @mmandk9 can you elaborate on "doesn't work" - what version of postgres are you on and what error message (if any) do you get?

Answer (score -3):

Just return the default value if no rows are found:

```
SELECT IFNULL(s_stock, 5)
  FROM stock_info 
 WHERE s_product_id = '43';
```

Comment: `IFNULL` is not valid syntax in Postgres (or standard SQL). It's used in MySQL.

Comment: If no row is found, nothing will be returned.